# Why this simple algorithm for finding the maximum number (among 3 numbers) can't print out the result?

Tags: java, algorithm, static-methods

My very simple program should sort out the maximum one among 3 numbers. I have used a static method for algorithm and called that into the main method. User should enter 3 floating numbers by using a space. afetr pressing enter the program should print out the biggest floating number. But it doen't. It just shows a bunch of errors. The attachment shows what error I have:

[image: error]

MaximumFinder.java:

```
    package maximumfinder;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MaximumFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner inScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 3 floating-pont value separated by space:");
        double num1 = inScanner.nextDouble();
        double num2 = inScanner.nextDouble();
        double num3 = inScanner.nextDouble();
        double result = maximum(num1, num2, num3);
        System.out.println("Maximum number is: "+result);
    }

    public static double maximum(double x, double y, double z) {
        double maximumValue = x;
        if (y > maximumValue) 
            maximumValue = y;
            //statement


        if (z > maximumValue) 
            //statement  
            maximumValue = z;



        return maximumValue;

    }
}
```

Comment: What errors does it show?  This is like going to your doctor and saying "I've got a bunch of symptoms".

Comment: Can you please share the errors?

Comment: ist //statement a command or real code? It it is code, you should use bracelets {} around that code. Is this your source of problems?

Comment: What is the input you're using and what output does it give you? Have you tried printing out the numbers the user entered to make sure `inScanner.nextDouble()` does what you think it does?

Comment: Works for me. Show the errors you have.

Comment: And as a corollary to my earlier comment, all the people who have provided answers without waiting to find out what the errors are, are like doctors saying "take two panadols and come back if you feel worse" without even bothering to examine the patient.  I really ought to give downvotes to everyone.

Comment: for the sake of all comments I have edited my post and there I attached my errors. please look on it.

Comment: what happens to your program when you provide a non-numeric input?

Comment: hfontanez, entering any non-numeric ( or just character if I understand correctly) value produces the same errors.

Comment: @Ryan it was a rhetorical question. I tried your input as shown in the image with your code (unchanged). It works for me. Unless you can guarantee that the inputs will always be numeric, you should validated them before using.

Comment: OK, what is your locale?  The reason for this question is to ascertain whether you are in a locale that uses comma instead of dot as a decimal separator, in which case dot might be interpreted as non-numeric.

Comment: @DavidWallace, good point. His profile says he's from Sweden. Using comma as decimal separator is very common in Europe.

Comment: hfontanez, David Wallace  and to all, Yes, that is the problem, my location. Finally it working with comma, instead of dot. because in europe we normally use comma bfore the decimal value, but in Paul Dietel's book has one exercise, where he used the dot. I was following the book. However using comma can output the maximum.

Comment: @Ryan - you could post that as an answer and do a self-accept.  That way, people will know that the question is "solved" without having to trawl through the comments.

Comment: David Wallace, please, tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

If I exclude the package declaration it is working perfectly fine for me
Just make sure that the class is in the right package.

Note : compile & run from command line.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you simply use the **max()** method from Java? It may solve your problem...

**EDITED**

I've tried your code and it runs perfectly, but I got **the same error** as you, if I type the double numbers using dots, like "3.5". If I type the numbers using commas("3,5") the program is executed till the end.

I hope this help you.

Comment: The questions isn't about what is best rather he asked why it isn't working :)

Comment: I know it, and the code seems to be right, but if we don't know what kind of errors are reported this could be an unexpected solution in the sense that the Math.max() method comes from the native code of Java

Comment: And also it's an optimal way to code it. At least, he could maybe learn something from my asnwer

Comment: for the sake of all comments I have edited my post and there I attached my errors. please look on it. –

Answer (score -1):

```
public static double maximum(double firstValue, double... otherValues) {
    double maximumValue = firstValue;
    for (double v : otherValues) {
        maximumValue = Math.max(maximumValue, v);
    }
    return maximumValue;
}
```

Comment: You should include explanatory text with your answer to help others know what you are doing.